# How do I search an object to see if it contains a username and password?

Tags: java

Currently I have got a textfile which contains the username and password and have put it in an object. However when trying to log in, it says array index out of bounds. Can not see what the error is.

```
    Object[][] data = new Object[UserDetails.size()][2];
    for(int i=1; i<UserDetails.size(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = UserDetails.get(i)[0];
            data[i][1] = UserDetails.get(i)[1];
            System.out.println(data[i][0]);
            System.out.println(data[i][1]);


    boolean match = false;
    boolean limit = false;
    int i=1;
    do{
        if((data[i][0] == username) && (data[i][1] == password)){
           match = true; 
        UsernameField.setText(null);
        PasswordField.setText(null);
        close();
        TablePage table;
        table = new TablePage(username);
        table.setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sucessfully Logged In","Login Success",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        close();
        }else{
            if(i == UserDetails.size()){
                limit=true;
            }
            i++;

        }

    } while(match==false || limit == true);
```

Comment: question is bit unclear with some variables `UserDetails` are not properly posted in the code. it may be helpful if you could post all the code.

Comment: don't hard coded your array indexes.

Comment: Why are you using such a terrible data structure? Surely what you really need is an array of `Pair<String, String>`?

Comment: I believe that you forgot to close the first `for` loop and the `if` statement in the `do/while` loop. If the braces were correct, this would mean that the **indentation** is wrong.

Comment: FYI in array Index starts from zero. Also your code has some errors. Where is closing braces of for loop. Initialize i to zero and in for loop and before do while loop.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ - specifically in your case, use a debugger (or, not as good, add `println(...)` statements) to look at the contents of the array, and the value of the index array before the failing statement runs.

Answer (score 1):

If `UserDetails.size() = 0`, then the size of data is [0][2].
Later you set i = 1, and and then have an `if(data[i][0])`.
This would cause an out of bounds error if `UserDetails.size() = 0`;

Comment: this's not the right answer not even explain the real problem also this question is not clear.